# 404 from Mechanical Turk when POSTing data

Tags: python, boto, mechanicalturk

I have an `ExternalQuestion` and I am trying to POST my data back to Mechanical Turk, which is done when the answer has been successfully completed. Here is what I'm doing:

```
 r = requests.post('https://workersandbox.mturk.com/externalSubmit', 
        data={
          'assignmentId': 'MY_ASSIGNMENT_ID',
          'answerText': 'SOME TEXT HERE'
        })
```

However, I get the following 404:

```
>>> r.status_code
404
```

What am I doing incorrectly here, and how would I POST my data to Mechanical Turk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL that you are using is invalid. According to [their documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_ExternalQuestionArticle.html) one of the following has to be used:

---

**The Form Action**

The form on the external website must post the result data back to Amazon Mechanical Turk using the following URL:

```
https://www.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit
```

Or, if you are using the Amazon Mechanical Turk sandbox, you should post the result data back to Mechanical Turk using the following sandbox URL:

```
https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit
```